# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /home/*****/public_html/lnews.php on line 22

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT news_title FROM news ORDER BY posted_time DESC");
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($news_title);
```

When I execute the code then it will return Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /home/*****/public_html/lnews.php on line 22. So, How can I fix this issue ?please help

Thank You

Comment: execute method `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: Your SQl query is not working, try to execute it yourself and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some error from database due to this the prepare method returns `FALSE`, on success this method returns prepared statement.

You can see the logs to determine the database error. Also, you should change your code in the following way and throw some exception in else.

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT news_title FROM news ORDER BY posted_time DESC");
if($results !== false) {
    $results->execute();
    $results->bind_result($news_title);
}
```

In this case if false return (if there is database error) the execute method would not be invoked.